# Redirect after imagepng function (Content-Type: image/png)

Tags: php

In some cases I want to redirect "header("Location: http://google.com");" on specific site, but page can't redirect after "imagepng($im);" function.

```
  $im = imagecreatefrompng("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-oOyCh939GVRH7snJ4o9UjvOhNueTR6TQM1Ca10A0DHyqediBDXqFS9uvyB8qyI7Rg=h400");
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    //imagedestroy($im);

    //header("Content-Type: text/html");
    //header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", TRUE, 301);
    header("Location: http://google.com");
```

Comment: That is correct. `header("Location: ")` should be called before anything is output to the screen. You'll need to find another way to do it, perhaps a javascript redirect.

Comment: Uhm, yes… you cannot show someone an image *and* redirect them to a different page in the same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't redirect on this position is the already sent header. So you have to be sure the header is not send using [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.headers-sent.php).

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.
>   **Source:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You can redirect on any position using a function like the following:

```
function redirect($url) {
    if(headers_sent() === true) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'."\n";
        echo '//<![CDATA['."\n";
        echo 'document.location.href="'.$url.'";'."\n";
        echo '//]]>'."\n";
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
}
```

**Is it possible that there is a problem with the logic of the code?**

The ouput of the image isn't needed if you want directly redirect after output. I think you need something like the following:

```
if ($dont_redirect) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-oOyCh939GVRH7snJ4o9UjvOhNueTR6TQM1Ca10A0DHyqediBDXqFS9uvyB8qyI7Rg=h400");
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    //imagedestroy($im);
} else {
    //header("Content-Type: text/html");
    //header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", TRUE, 301);
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
```

**Hint:** Make sure there is no output before the redirect!

Comment: This won't do a lot of good when an image is being output, and is also quite insane in general.